# Restore with deja-dup

Tags: restore, deja-dup, duplicate

I recently had a hard drive failure on my PC (ubuntu 12.04), I purchased a new Hard Drive & installed 14.04.

After installing the new Hard Drive my old one 'came back to life' so I continued using the old one (booting from it, filesystem etc). This wasn't the best move I'm aware, but the old Hard Drive contained all my progs file etc & I just didn't have time to swap everything over.

I did however backup everything on the old HD to the new HD using deja-dup, so my question is this, how do I go about restoring my data, also bearing in mind that I'm now using a different version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

To restore everything using Deja-Dup on 14.04

1. Start Deja-Dup
2. Click Overview in the left column. Move to the right and click the
   Restore... button
3. Browse to the location where you stored the backup. Click Forward.
4. After the "checking for backups" process finishes, choose the backup
   you want from the drop-down box. Click Forward.
5. Choose to restore to original locations or a folder of your choice. Click Forward.
6. Click that everything is as desired on the Summary screen, then
   click Restore to begin the process.