# recover from lost /home

Tags: 16.04, home-directory, restore

I am struggling to do this after a disk failure where my /home partition is held. I am unable to login on my original system but can use a live USB.

I have the original 16.04 system on a separate disk. Duplicity backup of /home on another disk.

I have created a new partition for my new home but do not know how to continue. I am not afraid of a fresh install if necessary, but since I have a backup do I need to?

Edit: no need for fresh install, the two answers below got me going, once I followed them exactly. I had everything I needed to reinstate my /home/user on a fresh partition.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk -f` with annotations (location of the Ubuntu installation, and the old and new home partitions) as well as the content of `/etc/fstab` so we know more about the system set-up. We can't help you decide what to do if we don't know the situation.

Comment: Thanks David, I edited my question to show I had followed the two answers and was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good, so you have a backup of the system and made a partition for /home. You only need to tell your system about that partition with the following instructions upon booting up the backup system:

1. Get the UUID for the newly created partition using `blkid` and finding the partition you just created, you'll find UUID variable that contains the value we need.
2. Edit /etc/fstab and replace the old UUID with the new UUID you just extracted from the previous step.
3. Just create the directories in the new partition- for each user with the proper permissions.
4. Reboot your system.

If you're stuck with any step comment on my answer and I'll reply.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the above: I am struggling with restoring /home/user from the duplicity backup.

Comment: I should have also said, that because there is curently no /home location and I have now physically disconnected the failed drive. I can't boot the system.   It hangs up at what I think is the command line.

Comment: So do you get a shell access?

Comment: I end up in "emergency mode" with the message "Press Enter for maintenance (or press Control-D to continue)

Comment: pressing Enter or Ctrl-D doesn't do anything.  So it looks to me as I have to boot from a live USB, which does work.

Comment: Then do it, and follow the steps above, just be sure to edit the /etc/fstab that belongs the backup system.

Comment: Thanks, have done that, editting the /etc/fstab on the original installation.

Comment: System still fails to boot fully, but I have a command line prompt "root@computer:~#"     The outstanding problem is to restore the duplicity backup to the new /home/user.

Comment: If you have a shell access, then you can follow the steps with no problem.

Comment: If the backup disk is connected, then you can see it when running `blkid`.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. All is fixed now, after I checked all the steps and corrected mistakes.  Not creating the correct permissions for the new home file was my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you can't get to the GUI on your normal boot disk, either by logging into `root` or another admin account. You may have to *tweak* the following steps to fit your particular results.

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt:

  `sudo mount -o rw,remount /` # to remount your disk in r/w mode

  `sudo blkid` # show UUID of new /home partition

  **copy** the UUID of the new /home partition to the clipboard

  `sudo pico /etc/fstab` # edit fstab using any editor you like

  replace the UUID in the line containing /home with a **paste** from the clipboard

  `reboot`

Now try and log into your normal account. If you've properly created the /home/your_username directory, you should be able to:

- Start Deja-Dup (Backups)
- Click Overview in the left column. Move to the right and click the
  Restore... button
- Browse to the location where you stored the backup. Click Forward.
- After the "checking for backups" process finishes, choose the backup
  you want from the drop-down box. Click Forward.
- Choose to restore to original locations or a folder of your choice. Click Forward.
- Click that everything is as desired on the Summary screen, then
  click Restore to begin the process.
- Note: above borrowed from [Restore with deja-dup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/755938/restore-with-deja-dup)

If you're not able to get to a GUI, you'll have to restore from the command line. Get back to the root # prompt, and make the disk r/w, as per above, and...

```
deja-dup --restore-missing DIRECTORY
```

See `man deja-dup` or `man duplicity` for more info.

Comment: Many thanks for this.  I got there after correcting a few mistakes, taking a rest and starting again was the key for me.

Comment: @JohnLangWilson Wow! Great you got it going. If there's any edits I can do to my answer to make it more correct, please let me know. Please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the grey checkmark icon if it was helpful. Thanks!